# Invalid property 'xxx' of bean class. Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am aware that this question has been asked before but after looking through all of the examples, non of the solutions helped me.

I am simply trying to render a video form on my application via spring controller, but I keep
getting the aforementioned error on every field except two. Below is my html

```
<form th:action="@{/upload-video}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" th:object="${video}">
    <input id="i_file" type="file" name="file" accept="video/*">
    <div class="video_container">
        <label for="video_name">Video Name</label>
        <input class="textInput" id="video_name" type="text" th:field="*{videoName}" placeholder="Example: image.png">
        
        <label for="videoDesc">Video Description</label>
        <input id="videoDesc" type="text" placeholder="Enter a description..." th:field="*{video_Description}">

        <label for="file_path">File Path</label>
        <input id="file_path" class="file_path_input textInput" type="text" placeholder="File Path..."><br>
        <video src="">
            Enter a video...
        </video>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

The error is now being generated on the videoDescription input tag. Below is my GET controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload-video", method = RequestMethod.GET)
private String uploadVideoPage(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("video", new Video());
    return "upload-video";
}
```

Here is my video class:

```
 @Entity()
 @Table(name = "user_videos")
 public class Video {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     private Long videoId;
     private String videoName;
     private String videoTagLine;
     private String video_Description;
     private Date uploadDate;
     @Transient
     private String uploadDateStr;

 public String getVideoName() {
         return videoName;
     }

 public void setVideoName(String videoName) {
        this.videoName = videoName;
     }

 public String getVideoTagLine() {
         return videoTagLine;
     }

 public void setVideoTagLine(String videoTagLine) {
        this.videoTagLine = videoTagLine;
     }

 public String getVideo_Description() {
        return video_Description;
     }

 public void setVideo_Description(String videoDescription) {
        this.video_Description = videoDescription;
     }

 public Date getUploadDate() {
        return uploadDate;
     }

 public void setUploadDate(Date uploadDate) {
        this.uploadDate = uploadDate;
     }

 public String getUploadDateStr() {
         return uploadDateStr;
     }

 public void setUploadDateStr(String uploadDateStr) {
         this.uploadDateStr = uploadDateStr;
     }
 }
```

I've google and googled and googled and non of the solutions have worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your property is `videoDescription` not `video_Description`. Property is th get/set methods not the fields in your class.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you saying that I need to change the name of my getters and setters? My class's property is video_Description. The name of my getters and setters is just a typo. They match the property name. I'll edit that.

Comment: That was what I was hinting at, however apparently that isn't the case as the code wasn't added properly. Please add the full stacktrace/error to your question.